# Adafruit ESP32 device working on OSX 10.13 but not on OSX 10.11 on older machine

Tags: adafruit, esp32

I'm new to Arduino - just got an ESP32-based Adafruit Feather HUZZAH32. I got it up and running on my Macbook Air (High Sierra) with no problem, following the instructions at this page linked from the [Adafruit page on the HUZZAH32](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather/using-with-arduino-ide):

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/mac.md (dead link)

Basically, install the Arduino IDE, install the Espressif stuff using a big shell command, and install the driver for the CP2104 USB->UART bridge.

It worked like a charm on the Macbook Air, no problem. But it was a different story when I went to install it on my 2009 vintage Mac Pro running El Capitan. Everything seemed to install ok, and the Arduino IDE runs and shows "Adafruit ESP32 Feather" (under Tools->Board).
However, when I try to upload a sketch (the "Blink" built-in example), it compiles ok but seems to hang while uploading, eventually finishing after about 5 minutes.  But the sketch isn't there, the one I previously uploaded from the HighSierra machine still executing.

Furthermore, it does weird things to the Mac: the System Profiler (About This Mac) no longer runs (shown as "Not Responding" in Activity Monitor), even after I've quit the IDE; occasionally I can't even seem to quit the IDE; and next time my computer sleeps, it can't be woken up (I have to restart with the power button).   Another thing: when I start the upload, the kernel-task (PID 0) starts using over 100% of the CPU (from Activity Monitor).

Maybe it's a version compatability issue with the Espressif uploader?   Or maybe I screwed up with the CP2104 driver, first installing the one here, [CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP Drivers](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers), as pointed to by the [How-To at Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather/using-with-arduino-ide), and when things did not work, and the uninstall shell script for the driver failed too, I just deleted what seemed to be the relevant files before then installing the "legacy" driver, which also did not work.

Looked at some of the debugging stuff here ... The CP2104 driver shows up under USB in System Profiler, and both `cu.SLAB_USBtoUART` and `tty.SLAB_USBtoUART` show up under `/dev` (in Terminal).   So nothing seems wrong there.

Here is a screen grab (with verbose output for upload selected):

```
Archiving built core (caching) in:
 /var/folders/qr/2l7_tnqx0m34h2sfbp218ykw0000gp/T/arduino_cache_759917/core/core_espressif_esp32_featheresp32_FlashFreq_80,UploadSpeed_921600,DebugLevel_none_4423141e818963094868f9e8ffa4e8ec.a

Sketch uses 136741 bytes (10%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.

Global variables use 10908 bytes (3%) of dynamic memory, leaving 284004 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 294912 bytes.
    
/Volumes/MainHD/Users/jge/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/esptool --chip esp32 --port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART --baud 921600 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 0xe000 /Volumes/MainHD/Users/jge/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/partitions/boot_app0.bin 0x1000 /Volumes/MainHD/Users/jge/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/sdk/bin/bootloader_dio_80m.bin 0x10000 /var/folders/qr/2l7_tnqx0m34h2sfbp218ykw0000gp/T/arduino_build_212318/Blink.ino.bin 0x8000 /var/folders/qr/2l7_tnqx0m34h2sfbp218ykw0000gp/T/arduino_build_212318/Blink.ino.partitions.bin
```

It just seems to be a very long command line to run esptool, and then... nothing.

I'm at a loss - I've asked at Adafruit forums: [trouble getting HUZZAH32 working on Mac](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=128986)

... and filed an "issue" at the Github page too: [upload hangs on older Mac configuration (Mac Pro 4,1 w/ El Capitan) #983](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/983)

In short, this Github issue says that the thing works fine on the USB ports on the rear of my Apple monitor, but hangs (as described in OP) on the ones on the front of the Mac Pro tower as well as the ones on the rear of the tower (including the one into which the monitor was plugged).

Comment: Is the difference USB 3.0 vs USB 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I think it may have to do with power, because I've run into some weird behavior, that seems power related, when I try to turn on wifi. And it's not the CP210X drivers, because it works on some ports and not others.  My machine only has USB 2.0 ports, and of course USB 3.0 can provide more power.   I'm going to buy an AC-powered USB hub and see if that works better.

Comment: The first link appears to have died, unfortunately. The guide appears to have been moved - could you please verify that this is now the link to the **same** guide that you followed: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/installing.html#macos. In addition, I have found that older versions of OS X do not work well with CH34x or CP210x USB interfaces (when they are used on an Arduino clone), the drivers just aren't there (not built-in to the OS).